# Get variables on a specific stack level in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to receive variables on specific stack level?

For example, I have class A that calls class B. In class B raises an exception. Can I get variables of A in that case?

```
class A
  def call
    B.new.()
  end
end

class B
  def call
    raise Exception.new('I want to get all the variables of caller A here.')
  end
end

A.new.()
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Ruby is really not designed to do this (without explicitly passing a binding).

Comment: I agree, never advise such a bad practice. But I would like to build similar to the https://www.takipi.com/features/main application. Idea is on the exception to save state of the variables on all the levels of stack. With binding_of_caller it's possible to do without any performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not in the core, but you can use an extension https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller

About the benchmarks: looks like it's [not loads](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller/blob/master/ext/binding_of_caller/binding_of_caller.c#L126) anything when it's `require`-d, because it's only gets Thread's data on call.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest thing to what you want is [`Binding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Binding.html).

```
class A
  def call
    variable = :value

    B.new.call binding
  end
end

class B
  def call(binding)
    binding.local_variable_defined? :variable    # true
    binding.local_variable_get :variable         # :value
  end
end

A.new.call
```

If you want to execute code with that specific binding, you can use [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Binding.html#method-i-eval):

```
class B
  def call(binding)
    binding.eval 'puts variable'
  end
end
```

Sadly, `eval` does does take a block.

---

> Forgot to say, I cannot pass any variables through the methods.

[There appears to be a gem for this](https://rubygems.org/gems/binding_of_caller).

Taking a quick look at [the source code](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller), it appears it accesses the internals of various Ruby implementations in order to invade the caller's privacy.

At this point I'd seriously consider if if it's really worth it. Keep in mind that you can't guarantee that `A#call` will always be the caller.

Comment: Forgot to say, I cannot pass any variables through the methods.

Comment: If anyone likes to go through the `Binding` methods and functionality: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Binding.html

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin, in that case it looks like someone already created a solution.